# Creating unique combinations of IDs

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up a database structure where each unique combination of players  get their own lineup_id. It is worth noting that there could be n amount of players on each team.

Below is an example of the table structure:

```
create table lineup_mapping (
lineup_id int,
player_id int,
primary key (lineup_id,player_id)
);

insert into lineup_mapping (lineup_id,player_id) values 
(1,25),(1,26),(1,14),
(2,15),(2,36),(2,25),
(3,25),(3,36),(3,25),(3,45);
```

I'll get a list of player_ids (in python) and I want to be able to look up whether this unique combination of player_ids already have their own lineup_id or whether I need to create a new one.

I figured it might be possible to use a combination of group by and distinct, but I am struggling to come up with any query that solves the whole task.

I should also point out that the order in which players appear does not matter. if they have played together that should count as a unique lineup_id.

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table.

Comment: Can you show which queries you came up with to solve parts of the problem? What the individual tasks are that are required to get the expected result? e.g. 1. generate lineup_id from player_ids 2. check if linup_id is in lineup_mapping ... It might help to achieve these individual steps first and only then combine the query, if that is indeed what you want. Sometimes it makes sense to stick with simpler queries and program the logic in a different language (i.e. python).

Comment: Thank you. Yes I figured that might be the case. Just wanted to make sure that there wasn't an obvious easy solution that I missed out on.

Comment: Player 25 is being inserted twice into lineup 3. Is that a typo?

Comment: No intentional as a player can play for multiple teams at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that works even if you don't know N ahead of time, or if the lineups don't necessarily all have the same number of players.

The idea is to build a unique key for each combination of players. For example you could sort the list of player ids and append them into a string. (E.g. players 1, 8, 3, and 4 would have the key "1-3-4-8".) If that key exists in your table, the lineup was already used.

We can create a new lineup-mapping table using these new keys:

```
INSERT INTO new_lineup_mapping (lineup_id, players_key) 
VALUES (1, '14-25-26'), (2, '15-25-26'), (3,'25-36-45-51');
```

The query would simply be:

```
SELECT lineup_id FROM new_lineup_mapping WHERE players_key = ?
```

Or, you can keep your original table structure and build the player keys on-the-fly. MySQL has a [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function that I think will work. The query would look something like:

```
SELECT lineup_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT player_id
                  ORDER BY player_id ASC SEPARATOR '-') AS players_key
FROM lineup_mapping GROUP BY lineup_id
HAVING players_key = ?
```

Either way, the code that calls the query would need to build the unique key for the list of players it is searching for. That's not ideal, but to solve that problem you would probably have to write a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If all the lineups have exactly N players, you can find the answer using the intersection of N subqueries. In MS SQLServer it might look something like this (N=3):

```
SELECT lineup_id FROM lineup_mapping WHERE player_id = <player1>
INTERSECT SELECT lineup_id FROM lineup_mapping WHERE player_id = <player2>
INTERSECT SELECT lineup_id FROM lineup_mapping WHERE player_id = <player3>
```

But MySQL doesn't have `INTERSECT` so you have to do a bit more work. One way:

```
SELECT map1.lineup_id FROM lineup_mapping map1 
WHERE map1.player_id = <player1> 
AND map1.lineup_id IN (
    SELECT map2.lineup_id FROM lineup_mapping map2 
    WHERE map2.player_id = <player2>)
AND map1.lineup_id IN (
    SELECT map3.lineup_id FROM lineup_mapping map3 
    WHERE map3.player_id = <player3>)
```

Not tested but hopefully you get the idea.